# Run directive after ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have a select input that loads the options from the model:

```
<select data-custom-select ng-model="adAccount" ng-options="adAccount.name for adAccount in adAccounts" class="cs-select cs-skin-border ad-accounts-select" >
    <option value="">Select an Ad Account</option>
</select>
```

I need to run some javascript after the options are filled. I created this directive:

```
(function(){
'use strict';

    define([
        'config',
        'angular',
        'selectFx',
        'application-modules/directives'
    ], function(config, angular, selectFx){
        var moduleId = 'customSelect';
        angular.module(config.app.name + '.directives').directive(moduleId, function($timeout){
            return {
                restrict: 'AEC',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                    $timeout(function () {
                        var sel = angular.element(element)[0];
                        new SelectFx(sel);
                    });
                }
            };
        });
    });
})();
```

The code inside `$timeout` is getting called before the options are filled in.

Comment: Directives are compiled following their priority number (greater comes first), so try to add `priority: 1` or try other numbers when you define your directive (along the `restrict` and `link` properties).

Comment: I already tried that with no luck. Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you set the `$tiemeout` of let's say 5 seconds, does it then work? If not, then it is not a compilation order issue.

Comment: setting the `$timeout` to 5 seconds worked..

Comment: @NicolásNistal, what are you actually trying to achieve? It *may* be that you are facing an XY problem.

Comment: I need to create a custom looking select input. The options that go into that select come from a model hooked to an API.

Comment: What do you mean by "model hooked to an API"? Do you mean, like in the case of `adAccounts`? And why do you need to know when DOM has finished loading all the `<options>` - aren't you the one who generates them?